# Monitor paper wallet balance without importing private key?

Tags: paper-wallet, watch-only

I generated a paper wallet offline and running from fresh OS, and I'm not going to ever type that private key into a computer until it's time to spend the coins.

But I will send coins to this address as a 'piggy bank'

My question: can the Qt client be configured to track an address and update the available balance for an address, without the private key ever being entered?

Comment: That would be a great addition. The paranoid amongst us might not want anyone else, e.g. a web service, know just which address we are watching.

Comment: you can do this from the commandline [with bitcoin-cli version 10+](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/36151/2116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of version 0.8.1, this is not possible with Bitcoin-Qt. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2121) to add support for watch-only addresses, which may make it into 0.9. Feel free to help testing!

Answer (score 7):

Try using [BlockChain.info](http://blockchain.info) - you can add a watch only address and then receive email or SMS alerts every time it does anything - so you don't even have to consciously keep an eye on it.

Edit: I apologise, I didn't see that you wanted to use QT for it. I don't know of any way to do this, so propose blockchain as an alternative.

Comment: Qt would be the most convenient, but 'watch only' address is what is was looking for tnx

Comment: It seems as if the question was suffering from a mild case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/202692). Your answer solves what he *meant* to ask, though. Upvote for you.

Comment: Another service that provides this type of monitoring is http://btcbalance.net .

Answer (score 3):

[Cointrack.net](http://cointrack.net) is a solution for users who need a convenient location to keep track of their various digital currencies stored in a variety of forms.

Cointrack does not store your coin; instead it displays any number of 
your address balances. It can also notify you of balance changes 
via email. This streamlines the process of keeping tabs on all
of your addresses, especially if they are stored remotely and/or on paper.

Answer (score 3):

I use Balances.io to track my Bitcoin, Litecoin and Dogecoin balances.  You never use a private key.  It simply monitors the balance contained in the public addresses.  I am not the owner of this website, only a user.  I am in a similar situation where I have cold storage wallets and I want to keep track of those balances.

https://balances.io/

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup a Bitcoin-Core (formerly Bitcoin-Qt) wallet on a separate, offline computer.
2. Import the private key.
3. Protect the wallet with a long, random gibberish password.
4. Forget or throw away the password.

You now effectively have a read-only wallet for your address, which you can safely use in other Bitcoin-Core installation, in online or potentially unsecure environments.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://blockonomics.co , you can easily track the balance of your address. You can also label your addresses and get email notifications on credits/ debits