# Bitcoind daemon get received notifications by public address

Tags: bitcoind

For my project I need to check the balance of a public address using bitcoind. Can I do that without importing the private key, only by public address?

Need solution no dependence, because I tried with blockchain.info API and after x requests, they blocked me. I need to check a lot addresses every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of polling many addresses every 30 minutes, you probably want to import your addresses into bitcoind, using `bitcoin-cli importaddress` and then have bitcoind notify you automatically when a new transaction comes in, using the `walletnotify` option.

See for example: [How do I use walletnotify?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/how-do-i-use-walletnotify)

There are a lot of details to get right: transactions might never confirm, the transaction ID might change. When bitcoind loses connection to the network, you want your script to be able to handle that. etc.

Comment: for import address bitcoind ask private key, I'm need solution only whit public key.

Comment: Bitcoind supports watch-only addresses with only the address. See here for more details:
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22152/add-a-watch-only-wallet-in-bitcoind